# Examples of Semantic Version Names

Tags: semantics

I have been reading about semver. I really like the general idea. However, when it comes to putting it to practice, I feel like I'm missing some key pieces of information. I'm not sure where the name of a library exists, or what to do with file variants. For instance, is the file name something like [framework]-[semver].min.js? Are there popular JavaScript frameworks that use semver? I don't know of any.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at `sbt` which is the Scala Build Tool. In it, we write dependencies like this:

```
 val scalatest = "org.scalatest" %% "core" % "2.1.7" "test"
 val jodatime = "org.joda" % "jodatime" % "1.4.5"
```

Wherein the operator `%%` means "the current version of Scala that you're building." Packaging things in this language generally create JAR files with the name like this `<my project>_<scala version>_<library version>.jar` which is quite handy for semantically naming things automagically. The `%` operator can be interpreted as "don't version this part."

That said, this resulted from the fact that the same library compiled to different Scala versions were not binary compatible with each other. So it was more as a result of, rather than a conscious design choice, the binary incompatibilities.

Comment: I am surprised. semver is not related to scala only I believe.

Comment: @sivatumma no, it is not related to only Scala. That said, it is a very good example of semver embraced by a language and the community.

Comment: I am still surprised. Questioner was asking about semver, (He was also concerned with javascript files mainly), And you told about Scala, which compiles to java compatible bytecode I believe. I am even more surprised how your answer is marked as correct by the Questioner.

Answer (score 8):

Let me try to explain you.
**If you are not developing a library that you like to keep for years to come, don't bother about it.**. If you prefer to version every development, read the following.

Suppose you are an architect or developer developing a library that is aimed to be used by hundreds of developers **over time**, in a distributed manner. You really need to be cautious of what you are doing, what your developers are adding (so interesting features that grabs your attention to push those changes in the currently distributed file). You dont know how do you tell your library users to upgrade. In what scenarios? People followed some sort of versioning, and interestingly, their thoughts all are working fine.

**Then why do you need semver ?**

It says **"There should be a concrete specification for anything for a group of people to follow anything collectively, even though they know it in their minds"**. With that thought, they made a specification. They have made their observation and clubbed all the best practices in the world about versioning *software mainly*, and given a single website where they listed them. that is [semver.org](http://semver.org). Its main principles are :

Imagine you have already released your library with a version **"lib.1.0.98"**, Now follow these rules for subsequent development.

Let your library is bundled and named as **xyz** and,

Given a version number MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH, (like  **xyz.MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH**), increment the:

```
 1. MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes
```

(existing code of users of your library breaks if they adapt this without code changes in their programs),

```
 2. MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner
```

(existing code works, and some improvements in performance and features also), and

```
 3. PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.
```

Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.

If you are not a developer or are not in a position to develop a library of a standard, you need not worry at all about semver.

Finally, the famous [[d3]](http://d3js.org) library follows this practice.

Comment: forgive me. I removed all words 'great' and 'big'.

Comment: =) I think you're still making the wrong emphasis though. It's not "If you're not going to keep the code for <ever>" rather "if you're writing some throwaway code you can _choose_ not to use semver" - generally speaking it's a good idea to version all code.

Comment: I don't intend to edit a different answer into your answer =), besides I'm not sure this actually answers the Author's question.

Answer (score 3):

[Semantic Versioning](http://semver.org/) only defines how to name your versions. It does not specify what you will do with your version number afterwards. You can put the version numbers in package names, you can store it in a properties file inside your application, or just publish it in a wiki. All those options are opened to discussion and not part of the problem space addressed by SemVer.

Answer (score 2):

semver is used by [npm](https://npmjs.org/) and [bower](http://bower.io/) (and perhaps some other tools) for dependency management. Using semver it is possible to decide which versions of which packages to use if multiple libraries used depend on the same library.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, it doesn't exactly answer my question about the syntax of semver or who actually uses it.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, semantic versioning is a standard versioning scheme that tells your users which versions of your library should be compatible with each other, and which ones are not.

The idea, is to be able to give your users more confidence that it's safe to upgrade to a newer patch/version, because it's tried, tested, and true to being backwards compatible with the previous version (minor increments). That is, perceptively that's what your telling your users.

As far as tooling goes, I don't do much in javascript, but I typically let my build server handle stamping my assemblies etc with the correct version. I have a static major number I upgrade whenever I make breaking changes, a static minor number I upgrade everytime I add new features, and an auto-incrementing Patch number whenever I checkin bug fixes.

Especially if this is a javascript library you plan to share on a public repository of some kind (nuget, gem, etc) you probably want some for of automated packaging system, and you put the logic in there for specifying your version number (in the package meta data, in the name of the javascript file, which is typically the standard I've seen).